# Suppose $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers that satisfy the system equations

Tags: diophantine-equations

Suppose $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers that satisfy the system equations :

$x^2y$+ $y^2z$ + $z^2x$ $= 2186$

$y^2x$+ $z^2y$ + $x^2z$ $= 2188$

What is $x^2+y^2+z^2$ ?

Comment: Unsourced, unmotivated, no evidence of any thought/work on part of OP --- not the best usage of this website.

Comment: @Oleg, "original poster" (or, in some contexts, "original post").

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting the first equation from the second, we have:
$$ y^2(x - z) + z^2 (y-x) + x^2(z-y) = 2$$
 $$ \implies \qquad (x - z)(y-x) (y - z) = 2 \tag {3}$$

Now considering the possible integer factors of 2, could you solve for possible $(x, y, z)$?

---

**ADDITIONAL HINTS**

a) The difference between these integers can be only among $\pm1, \pm2$, and should satisfy (3). So assume $x=a$ and $x <y<z$, can you write $y$ and $z$ in terms of $a$?  What if the ordering is different - are there other solutions?

b) To find $a$, substitute solutions obtained from above into your first equation.

Comment: i've tried but i didn't find that  it's equal to  down vote favorite
 

Suppose x, y, and z are integers that satisfy the system equations :

$x2y+ y2z + z2x =2186$

$y2x+ z2y + x2z =2188$

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say!  Follow the path suggested, you will get a form for $(x, y, z)$ with only one parameter.  Substitute into any equation, you will get the value for the parameter and hence the answer needed.  Do try yourself.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how the first equation in the (3) implies the second.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You could expand and factorise the LHS, or expand both LHS and note they are the same, or simply note that $x=y$ makes the first LHS zero, hence $(x-y)$ is a factor.  Similarly for the other factors, and the constant can be determined by checking the coefficient of any power, say of $x^2y$.

Comment: @Mcavity how did you figure out how to factor like that when you solved this problem? Did you see that x=y is a solution?

Comment: @Ovi A curious thing about the problem was that the cyclic sums were only 2 apart. So I hoped for a factorisation of 2, and it turned out to be simple. Not many generic strategies for Diophantine problems, unfortunately.